# Can master pdf editor or some other software allow me edit pdf bookmarks arbitrarily?

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

1. I try to edit bookmarks of a pdf file under master pdf editor. Maybe
   I miss something, but I can't create a new bookmark at the same
   level or at a higher level than some existing bookmarks. (e.g.
   create a bookmark for chapter, to group the existing section
   bookmarks under it). All I can is to create a new bookmark under an
   existing bookmark. DO I miss something?
2. I could but now can't invoke my pdfexchange by

   ```
   $ wine pdfexchange 1.pdf
   fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"ABBYY.Licensing.FineReader.Professional.10.0" failed to start: 2
   wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\pdfexchange.exe"
   ```

   Not sure why.

Are there other applications on Ubuntu that can allow me to arbitrarily edit pdf bookmarks? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two very good alternatives to Master PDF editor as far as PDF bookmarks are concerned, [jPdf Tweak](http://jpdftweak.sourceforge.net/) and [JPdfBookmarks](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpdfbookmarks/). Both are open-source and require Java. I suggest you give them a try and see which one suits your needs.